# Is it possible to receive google directions by intent

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, google-maps-android-api-2

I was able to start an intent to get directions in the google maps app:

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.de/maps/dir/[adress1]/[adress2]/[adress3]"); 
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Now I am wondering if it is possible to pass the selected route to my original app using an intent, result receiver or something similar.

Comment: As far as I know and as also mentioned in this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_google_maps.htm), Android allows us to integrate google maps in any Android application wherein you can show any location or can show different routes on the map. Have you not considered integrating Google maps in your app instead?

Comment: Integrating Google Maps into the app will certainly work, thanks. I was just wondering if there is also a possibility using intents.